# Where is a good place for me to declare / initialize $scope variables for my module?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

```
angular.module('admin')
    .controller('AdminContentController',
    ['$scope', '$resource', 'gridService', 'gridSelectService', 'localStorageService', 'utilityService',
    function ($scope, $resource, gridService, gridSelectService, localStorageService, utilityService ) {

        localStorageService.add('ls.adminPage', 'content');
        $scope.entityType = 'Content';
        gridService.gridSetup($scope);
```

and:

```
angular.module('admin')
    .factory('gridService',
    ['$resource', '$timeout', 'gridSelectService', 'localStorageService', 'utilityService',
    function ($resource, $timeout, gridSelectService, localStorageService, utilityService) {
        var factory = {
            gridSetup: function ($scope) {
                $scope.grid = {
                    fetching: false,
                    pristine: true,
                    pageType: 'Edit'
                }
```

I am initializing the scope variables in the service but I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this.

Is there a better way for me to set up $scope variables for the module in another place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its good practice to store  variables into service.

Services are Singletons that you can inject to any controller and expose their values in a controller's scope.

However, you can't inject `$scope` into services, there is nothing like a singleton $scope.
You can implement `factory` by this way:

```
myApp.factory('gridService',
    ['$timeout',
    function ( $timeout) {

        var grid = {
                    fetching: false,
                    pristine: true,
                    pageType: 'Edit'
                }        

       return {
            gridSetup: function () {                
               return grid;
            },
           setGridSetup: function (newGrid) {
               grid = newGrid;
            }
        }
        }]);
```

And we use our factory from controller:

```
$scope.newGrid = gridService.gridSetup();
$scope.copyGrid = angular.copy($scope.newGrid);


$timeout(function() {
   $scope.copyGrid.pageType = "Fess"; 
    gridService.setGridSetup($scope.copyGrid);   
     $scope.newGrid = gridService.gridSetup();
}, 3000);
```

We load out model, after 3 sec we change `pageType` and store it again. after next load we get modified model.

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PxdSP/794/)</kbd>

Comment: How about the way that I initialize the service. Could this be done in a better way. I was wondering about the .init of the module.

Comment: @Alan - to best of my understanding - service is initiated at the time of injection into a controller - and because services are singletons (one instance per app) should you use service in multiple places this single instance will be injected everywhere. For more in dept explanation watch this  presentation by Wes Alvaro  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxuN6WO3tIA&list=PL53194065BA276ACA&index=6 / slider here: http://slides.wesalvaro.com/20121113/